# Can drawable and layouts be shared in a Android Project Library?

Tags: android, android-layout, shared-libraries

I am actually trying this, but I get a lot of red underlines in my Eclipse.
I can't describe my problem in details, so I just ask in general:

Can drawable and layouts be shared in a Android Project Library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Stop using Eclipse as soon as you can. Android development on Eclipse leads nowhere. Google is evolving Android Studio and Eclipse is long-forgotten. The sooner you jump into using Android Studio the better.
2. Yes, resources of the Android Project Library can be shared with the projects that are using this library. `<public/>` type of resource is the one you should be looking at. You can read more about it [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/private-resources).

Comment: Thanks. Did not know that Eclipse is out of date regarding development of apps. Thanks,